# How to solve ConversionNotSupportedException from 'com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl' to required 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory'

Tags: jboss, migration, ibm-mq, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I am trying JBOSS EAP 6.4 to JBOSS EAP 7.2 migration.

At the server startup I am getting

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'A' defined in ServletContext resource Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'queueManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'queueManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: It sounds like you are missing MQ JAR files.  See this link: http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398

Comment: I have added the jar files

Comment: It is printing, DEPLOYMENT name = wmq.jmsra.rar [org.infinispan.commons.util.ServiceFinder]  No service impls found: ModuleLifecycle is this the culprit?

Comment: Is this jar 'mq jar' getting successfully deployed or is it getting undeployed after above error,if so that could be the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so much trying, I solved this error by adding `javax.jms.api` to the global-modules section in `standalone.xml`. It resolves above issue with the `WMQ` setup.

```
<global-modules>
    <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
</global-modules>
```

Comment: I had same problem.  After so much trying, I solved this error by your Answer, :)